# pycharm import files into project

Tags: pycharm

[image]I have an dir A which contain some py files. I want use pycharm to debug those python files. However, I can not create pycharm project on A dir because A is a subdir in version control. So I create the project into another place like B. Then I need import files under A to this new created project.

I google this find it can be done by add content root, after I do this, I can see those files in project, however the added path is not subdir of the created root path. When I run the py file, it report an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PathA/xx.py'
```

How to do this? I use pycharm community 2018.2. The created project use venv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember fore version can import files from other location. This newest version can not do this. The only way is create the project in the directory which hold by version control tool. However, pycharm only will create 2 directories which are `.idea` and `venv`. Just let version control tool to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do, apologies if so.

If you drag and drop your file onto your project folder then click 'refactor' in the pop-up window that should work

I'm not authorised to add images I'm afraid (first ever post) or I would have added some screenshots.

I appreciate the post is pretty old, but thought it might help someone else.

Comment: You can still add images. You just can't embed them. If you add screenshots, just tag me when you're done, and I'll embed them in your post on your behalf.